# AngularFire Cannot update document because document reference ID could not be fetched

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm making an update function that would fetch the required document based on it's document uid which is tied to the authenticated user's uid.

in another function where I'm fetching the data from the collection using the same method which works fine, but on the function where I'm storing the uid as a variable it returns me as an [object object].

this is the function called to retrieve my current user data

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```

this will then get me the fields that i needed by plainly calling e.g. user.username

however when trying to store the document uid as such

```
this.userID = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.userID = user.uid;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```

My userID's value will just be [object object]

when called this

```
updateUser(user: User) {
    this.userDoc = this.afs.doc(`users/${this.userID}`);
    this.userDoc.update(user);
  }
```

returning an undefined document path of .../documents/users/[object Object]

how would I then be able to trace the document ID for the updating to work?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.userID = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.userID = user.uid;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```

into this:

```
this.userID = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.userIDs= user.uid;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```

You need to use a different variable (this.userIDs) name to store the `user.uid`

Comment: Is there a reason why a new variable needs  to be declared to solve this? Also using this only returned me an undefine instead

Comment: Can u do `console.log(user)`

Comment: With console.log(user) it returns me the field of data from the document fetched and updated, however on console.loh(this.usersID) it returns me an undefined

Comment: You are using `this.userID = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(` here and `this.userID = user.uid` thats why I told you to change the variable because its returning `[object object]` which is this `this.afAuth.authState.pipe(`

Comment: And when I'm setting it as  `this.userIDs= user.uid;` instead of [object object] i'm getting undefined. however the parameter `user` i'm passing in contains the array of fields i want to store

Comment: but does it contain a `uid`?

Comment: for my update function no, my user document only has username, gender and age field. It is in `this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user)` that I'm getting the authentication user's uid as the document id

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are storing the assigning both the value to `this.userID` as well as the subscription to `this.userID`. Remove the assignment: `this.userID = this.afAuth.authState` and now it will be stored correctly! Instead store the subscription in another variable that you can then unsubscribe to when needed:

```
this.mySubscription = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.userID = user.uid;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
);
```